# How do you report on Half Year 1 vs Half Year 2?

Tags: reporting

I would like to establish a way to be able to report and compare H1 (first 6 months of a year) vs. H2 in addition to the current options (quarters, months, weeks) for the most relevant date fields of a custom object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any other option than the current filters, you may need to resort to a formula field. For example:

```
TEXT(YEAR(MyDateField__c)) & " " & IF(MONTH(MyDateField__c)<7, 'H1','H2')
```

This would allow you to group by half-years in a report or SOQL statement.